# Get the number of cores in Erlang with Linux

Tags: erlang

i am writing a concurrent program and i need to know the number of cores of the system so then the program will know how many processes to open.
Is there command to get this inside Erlang code?

Thnx.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand why you'd need to limit the number of processes to the number of cores? Erlang has a preemptive scheduler, so even if you have 100000 processes on a duel core machine they will all get an equal share of CPU time, more or less.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
erlang:system_info(logical_processors_available)
```

to get the number of cores that can be used by the erlang runtime system.

Comment: This returns `unknown` for me (Intel Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro Mid 2009 with OS X 10.9.4)

Answer (score 10):

There is also:

```
erlang:system_info(schedulers_online)
```

which tells you how many scheduler threads are actually running.

Comment: This seems a better way because it respects the +S option given to `erl`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of available cores, use the [`logical_processors`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#logical_processors) flag to [`erlang:system_info/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info-1):

```
1> erlang:system_info(logical_processors).
8
```

There are two companion flags to this one: [`logical_processors_online`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#logical_processors_online) shows how many are in use, and [`logical_processors_available`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#logical_processors_available) show how many are available (it will return `unknown` when all logical processors available are online).

To know how to parallelize your code, you should rely on [`schedulers_online`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_schedulers_online) which will return the number of actual Erlang schedulers that are available in your current VM instance:

```
1> erlang:system_info(schedulers_online).
8
```

Note however that parallelizing on this value alone might not be enough. Sometimes you have other processes running that need some CPU time and sometimes your algorithm would benefit from even more parallelism (waiting  on IO for example). A rule of thumb is to use the value obtained from `schedulers_online` as a multiplier for parallelism, but always test with different multiples to see what works best for your application.

Answer (score 0):

How this information is exposed will be very operating system specific (unless you happen to be [writing an operating system](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-64-architecture-processor-topology-enumeration/) of course).

You didn't say what operating system you're working on. In the case of Linux, you can get the data from /proc/cpuinfo, however there are subtleties with the meaning of hyperthreading and the issue of multiple cores on the same die using a shared L2 cache (effectively you've got a NUMA architecture).

Comment: I am using Linux OS, when erlang start in the shell there is smp 4:4
so i guess that the VM know the number of cores
so how can i get this information?